# Differentials word problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The Questions

Use differentials to find the approximate amount of copper in the four sides and bottom of a rectangular tank that is 6 feet long, 4 feet wide, and 3 feet deep inside, if the copper is $1/4$ inch thick

So I've got he set up of $dV=whdl + lhdw + lwdh$, however I don't quite see where I can obtain the information for $dl, dw, dh$.

Answer (score 1):

$dl$, and $dw$, are $\frac{1}{2}$, since we add $\frac{1}{4}$ of copper to both sides. However, $dh$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ because there is no second side; there is only a bottom and not a top.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I also don't quite understand how to pick out the value of w, l, and h?

Comment: shouldnt it be 1/2 since its 1/4th thick on BOTH SIDES of the tank, and therefore 1/2 inch total?

Comment: Why is the copper on both sides of the tank? My understanding is that sides and bottom are coated/"painted" with copper, so it would only be on one side.

Comment: OH I see what you mean now. Yes, but only two of the are $\frac{1}{2}$. The bottom, since there is not top, **is** $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: So, dl is 1/2, dw is 1/2, and dh is 1/4. Would you mind revising the answer to reflect this?